# Duplicate close reason: Allow linking to duplicates on other sites

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I thing an example would speak best of all:

Just asked on Programmers (actually migrated from StackOverflow):

[Please remind me of a famous programming quote!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36498/please-remind-me-of-a-famous-programming-quote)

There is a perfect duplicate:

[Great programming quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes)

But it's impossible to close the question as a duplicate because the duplicate is on another site.

How shall we proceed? Migrate the question back to SO?

Comment: Likewise: among the many metas? Like on MSU [What backend / CMS Scipting is this site running?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1889/what-backend-cms-scipting-is-this-site-running) was migrated from Super User, but its duplicate [What was Stack Overflow built with?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with) is at MSO. (Luckily, other duplicates that were once migrated from MSO to MSU still refer to that, so the chain of duplicates on MSU still gets one to MSO.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best course of action in this specific case would actually be to migrate the [Great programming quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes) question to P.SE. It's a better fit there than it is on SO. Then you could close the newer question as a duplicate like you want to.

In reference to the larger suggestion of being able to close a question as a duplicate of a question on another site, that just sounds too complicated and I doubt anyone would even use it much anyway. Think about it... how often is anyone going to go rooting around on *another* site looking for duplicates when users usually don't even search enough for duplicates on the *current* site they're on. Besides, if a duplicate exists on another site it sounds more like an issue to be dealt with by migration (i.e. one of them is probably in the wrong place).

Comment: That probably makes sense to migrate that question to Programmers.

Comment: I actually didn't leave on "rooting around" just remembered there was this particular question somewhere there so I only needed to get a link to it. Long-term members would probably do it but not newcomers that's true.

Comment: I would use it. And users seem to tell us on Unix SE of crossposting all the time.