# Cast a close vote on duplicate which is not on SO

Tags: discussion

There is a scenario where someone asks the "same" question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739988/akward-delay-to-connect-apaches-proxy-request-to-a-node-js-app) and also on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/262036/akward-delay-to-connect-apaches-proxy-request-to-a-node-js-app) and it get answered there. Now when I try to close the question on SO as a duplicate and pass ServerFault link it references different question which has the same ID but relevant to SO and not ServerFault. Is there a way to close questions as duplicates when they are answered on different sites?

Comment: Surely the question is "off topic" on one of the sites rather than a duplicate. Strictly it should be migrated and then closed (and possibly merged).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate close reason: Allow linking to duplicates on other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74895/duplicate-close-reason-allow-linking-to-duplicates-on-other-sites)

Answer (score 1):

I would flag it as "does not belong here", or maybe "required moderator's attention" and link the SF page in a comment.